# Bulk downloading data with a limiter

Tags: julia, bulk, download

So, I am writing a function which basically bulk downloads data and saves it in db.
Firstly, I had simply put it as

```
function storedata(url_list)
  for url in url_list
    data = downloaddata(url)
    savedataindb(data)
  end
end
```

But this way the downloading was pretty slow (my guess is that the data-server itself limits the speed)
So I asynchronized all the downloads so that I can place several download calls at once

```
function storedata(url_list)
  @sync for url in url_list
    @async savedataindb(downloaddata(url))
  end
end
```

This works and downloads pretty quickly.
But my url_list is pretty big, and so this just makes too many calls to the data-server and the data-server blocks me.
So, I thought, I will instead create batches of certain size, to download asynchronously, as follows

```
function storedata(url_list)
  batches = divide(url_list)
  @sync for batch in batches
    @async for url in batch
      savedataindb(downloaddata(url))
    end
  end
end
```

But this also doesn't solves the problem. The same previous issue remains.

How do I implement this function so that I can place several download calls at once but also limiting them (in some sense) at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not fully reproducible, but if `length(batches)` is small then it should work OK I think (i.e. when number of entries in `batches` collection is the way you want to limit the number of asynchronous requests).

If on the other hand you make each entry of `batches` the same size, i.e. when `length(batch)` is small and tuned to the limit your server accepts you could check:

```
function storedata(url_list)
  batches = divide(url_list)
  for batch in batches
    @sync for url in batch
      @async savedataindb(downloaddata(url))
    end
  end
end
```

I have not tested it as your code was not runnable. Does it help?